# How to resize images when exporting to Markdown format?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown, exporting

Is there an equivalent of `#+attr_html: :width 500px` for Markdown format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markdown exporter doesn't appear to export image sizes defined by `#+attr_html:` or `#+attr_org:` (the `ox-gfm` exporter doesn't either)

so, you could either include raw html in the org file, which does get exported...

`#+html: <img src="img/test.png" width="600px">`

or if you have pandoc installed, you can use it as an external process to convert from org to markdown. The conversion will include image properties defined in the `#+attr_org:` lines...

`pandoc -i test.org -o test.md`